# 2017 equivalent of Wix ClickThrough

Tags: c#, wix, installation, auto-update

I've recently gotten involved in using **Wix** to create an installer for my `C#` application.

I'm looking for some functionality that provides the ability to auto-update or check for updates in some fashion.

From my searches I've found that `ClickThrough` used to be a thing, and now the page is no longer available on the Wix website, so I assume it's not around anymore.

**Is there a modern version of `ClickThrough` that is compatible with wix?**

If needed, I do already have a website that is hosted and live if I needed somewhere for the application to check for updates from.